# Cambiar Formato de Fecha - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo se podria cambiar el formato una fecha la cual recibo por *POST*: `24/01/2017` (dd/mm/aaaa) a este formato `2017/01/24` (aaaa/mm/dd)?

```
$fecha1= $_POST['fecha1'];
```

El detalle es que cuando lo inserto en MySQL me cambia el formato y lo registra como `2024/01/17` siendo el valor `{24/01/2017}`.

Comment: Recuerda que el formato tipo **date** en MySQL tiene por defecto `yyyy-mm-dd` lo unico que debes hacer es enviarlo de esa forma de una manera simple `$fecharMysql = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha1));`

Comment: @Mariano gracias valoraré tu consejo debido a que estas en lo cierto

Answer (score 4):

Podrias usar algo como esto:

```
<?php

$fecha1 = "24/01/2017"; // Obviamente se cambia por $_POST['fecha1'];

$fechaNueva = date('Y/m/d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fecha1)));

echo $fechaNueva . "\n";

?>
```

Lo que hacemos es cambiar los *slash* por  *guiones*, para que este sea mas facil de leer hacia la funcion *strtotime*.

Este error ocurre por lo siguiente *(Segun la documentacion de PHP)* [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php):

> Nota:
>   Las fechas en los formatos m/d/y o d-m-y no son ambiguas al observar el separador entre los distintos componentes: si el separador es una barra (/), se asume el formato norteamericano m/d/y; mientras que si el separador es un guion (-) o un punto (.), se asume el formato europeo d-m-y. Si, sin embargo, el año se proporciona en un formato de dos dígitos y el separador es un guion (-, la cadena de la fecha se analiza como y-m-d.

Resultado:

> 2017/01/24